# Is it possible to parse the hmac_sha256 signature returned by the server

Tags: hmacsha256

Made a client, initiated a consumption transaction, and signed the data to be sent with hmac_sha256. Whether the signature returned by the server can be parsed

I signed the data with hmac_sha256 and posted it to the server. It was successful and I received the signature returned by the server. How should I parse the returned signature?

Comment: You can use the servers public key to decrypt the signature, which will result in a hash of the content. You can then hash the content yourself to see if the hashes match.